# Can I customize vscode comment symbols？

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Like this captrue show, I am writing arm assemble code, and I use vscode as my editor, vscode installed arm assemble plugin and it recognized this code.

But when I want to comment some code, vscode use "@", I want change it to "//", Can I customize vscode comment symbols？

[captrue1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Isy9W.png)

Comment: You could try this extension I wrote: https://github.com/ArturoDent/custom-language-properties.  What is the assemble plugin?

Comment: vscode plugin name is：Arm Assembly，author ： dan-c-underwood

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the [Custom Language Properties](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.custom-language-syntax) extension.
2. From the Command Palette, run the command `Custom Language Properties: Check for new language extensions`.
3. Create a setting in your `settings.json` like this:

```
"custom-language-properties": {

},
```

When you type `"arm." in that setting, like

```
"custom-language-properties": {
  "arm."           // should suggest `comments.lineComment`
},
```

Choose that and it will complete with the default line comment `@` - just change that to whatever you want.

```
"custom-language-properties": {

  "arm.comments.lineComment": "//"
},
```

and your line comments for `arm`-language files should now be `//`.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: This is a great extension!

Comment: Another question, I met this situation. My home PC connect company VPN, and I open vscode, my vscode installed a plugin named Remote Development , the version is v0.21.0, so that I can connect my company PC and coding which I need not save any code in my home PC. In this case the plugin "Custom Language Properties" does not work. Whether it is local vscode or remote vscode, I have setting.json yet, like below:  
"custom-language-properties": {
        "arm.comments.lineComment": "//"
}
but the coment character still "@"
So I want to know, does this plugin work in this situation?

Comment: I just pushed a change to v0.5.3 that may help in this regard.  Update to it and let me know if it helps.  [And I assume you ran step 2 above?]

Comment: And will it work on your home system only?  Can you install the extension there and test it?  Just to see if it works there.

Comment: I update home system and remote system plugin to version 0.5.3
I tested on home pc and compant pc respectively and it all worked
But if I use home pc connect to company pc, this plugin will failed
I have an issue in this repo, and there are some screenshot, may show my quesiton clearly
[issue](https://github.com/ArturoDent/custom-language-properties/issues/3)